# Stylistic question regarding \label and fancyref: what to do with redundancy?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, fancyref

Suppose you are writing a document that is fairly structured, e.g. documentation to a package or a compound thesis describing many experiments. One may come across redundant section titles e.g. methods. Inclusion of  ''meta'' information e.g. `\label{sec:methods}`, will prevent redundancy and confusion when the label `methods` has different scopes (e.g. `fig`, `ch`, `sec`, etc). However, this is not the case when the label shares the same scope, e.g.

```
\chapter{experiment one}\label{ch:experiment-one}
\section{methods}\label{sec:methods}

\chapter{experiment two}\label{ch:experiment-two}
\section{methods}\label{sec:methods}
```

Thus my question is, following LaTeX conventions of course, how to handle this? Should I simply prepend the encapsulating element? e.g.

```
\section{methods}\label{ch:experiment-one_sec:methods}
```

Comment: you can not have two `\label` with the same value, It doesn't matter what that value is you can use  `\section{methods}\label{zzzz}` then `\section{methods}\label{abababaab}` so long as you use the same label when you `\ref` the section.

Comment: What is the connection of your posting with the `fancyref` package? Having non-unique labels will cause a problems irrespective of whether or not the `fancyref` package is loaded.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I am aware of that, hence the question on the stylistic appropriate way to handle redundancies

Comment: @Mico the fancyref package I think has a way of inferring where to link to if you have multiple labels with different meta information e.g. ch:methods, sec:methods, and fig:methods. Since fancyref relies on the meta information, whereas it is otherwise optional, I figured those who are accustomed to it might better answer the question.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that `fancyref` parses the contents of `\label` instructions. As David has already commented, though, LaTeX has a non-negotiable requirement that labels be unique. (This is a mark of sanity, really; I don't see how anything good might come if repeated labels were allowed.) Having two `\label{sec:methods}` instructions in a LaTeX document is going to create problems whether or not `fancyref` is employed in the creation of cross-references. Thus, the main syntax rule remains: Labels must be unique.

Comment: @Mico I believe we have a miscommunication regarding my question. I am aware of everything that you have said softer and I am not using redundant labels. My question was as to if there existed a stylistic convention for when such an instance occurred.

Comment: "I am not using redundant labels". I guess I was thrown off by the presence of the repeated `\label{sec:methods}` instructions in your code snippet. My apologies. The only stylistic rule `fancyref` cares about is that a label associated with a `\section` instruction should start with `sec:` (unless the default settings have been changed). Neither `fancyref` nor LaTeX impose any other (stylistic) requirements.

Comment: your example isn't helping to clarify the question as all that is an example of is a case with a repeated label?

Comment: ideally fancyref would be fixed not to rely on a particular form of the label argument, but while that's not the case you just need to do whatever it needs, you can't really ask about latex conventions as the convention is the label is just an internal private string for cross references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun: referencing a label which includes another reference.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref

\newcounter{methods}
\begin{document}
\chapter{experiment one}\label{ch:experiment-one}
\section{methods}\label{sec:methods.\thechapter}

See \ref{sec:methods.\getrefnumber{ch:experiment-one}} and \ref{sec:methods.\getrefnumber{ch:experiment-two}}.

\chapter{experiment two}\label{ch:experiment-two}
\stepcounter{methods}%
\section{methods}\label{sec:methods.\thechapter}
\end{document}
```